# How to generate html from a json response in react

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a json response which contains html tags with their corresponding attributes and classes. I am supposed to generate an html page in react with the json data. I have implemented it using recursion but I'm thinking there will be a optimized react way of doing it. can anyone help me?
link to code on sandbox [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/page-generator-v5698c?file=/src/App.js)

code :

```
import "./styles.css";
import Response from "./response.json";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
   console.log("response body", Response.BODY.INNER);
   console.log("app");
   const pageData_ = Response.BODY.INNER;
   let htmlString = "";

   const loop = (pageData) => {
   let innerHtml = "";

   for (const element of pageData) {
      let firstKey = Object.keys(element)[0];

      let objWithAttrib = { ...element[firstKey] };
      delete objWithAttrib.INNER;

  let attributeString = Object.keys(objWithAttrib)
    .map((key) => {
      return `${key.toLowerCase()}="${objWithAttrib[key]}"`;
    })
    .join(" ");

  innerHtml +=
    firstKey !== "TEXT"
      ? `<${firstKey.toLowerCase()} ${attributeString}>`
      : `${element[firstKey]}`;

  let children = "";
  if (element[firstKey].INNER) {
    children += loop(element[firstKey].INNER); // recursion 
    innerHtml += `${children}</${firstKey.toLowerCase()}>`;
  }

  
}
return innerHtml;

};

const validate = (number) => {
  return;
 };


 let xyz = loop(pageData_).toString();

 xyz += `<script>
 const validate = (index) => {
 return;
 };
 </script>`;

return <div className="App" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: xyz }}></div>;
}
```

[image: generated image]

Comment: I'd recommend you to change the API of json file and use `React.createElement` function

Comment: @Yoskutik i don't get you can you please explain? i can't change the api from the json file because that's what i will get from the backend. so how can i use the createElement in react to achieve this?